Proper formatting to get directory for Robocopy
Because of limitations on which Powershell modules are installed, I am trying to write a script that uses Get-ACL, Set-ACL, Get-ChildItem to migrate folders and permissions from one server to another.
$Directory = Get-ChildItem -Path d:\home -Recure -Force| ?{$_.PSIsContainer} |Select-Object FullName

foreach($Dir $Directory)
{
    robocopy "$Dir" "\\<dest server>\home" /mir /copy:datou /r:1 /w:10exit
}

When I run this Powershell is assuming that the source is under C:\Users<user>@{FullName=$Dir
when I want the source to be just the value of $Dir
Can anyone help?

Change |Select-Object FullName to |ForEach-Object FullName or |Select-Object -ExpandProperty FullName
